# How to change the scale of my matplotlib y axis to y^2?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphing, yaxis

Instead of the y-axis being 1,2,3,4... Is there a way to make it 1,4,9,16...? 
Can't find anything on the website.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(100))
y = 2 * np.pi * (x/9.81)**(1/2)

plt.figure()

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Graph")
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to change your y-axis ticks or do you want to draw a straight line for this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just want to replace the tick labels. In that case, you can do the following.

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Graph")
plt.grid(True)

yticks = np.arange(1,20,1)

plt.yticks(yticks, yticks**2)

plt.show()
```

[image]